# What is configFile() and how is it different from file() in Android Lint?

Tags: android-gradle-plugin, lint

## Background

[Lint](https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.LintOptions.html#N12C0E) is a [Static Code Analysis Tool](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Static_Code_Analysis) that scans Android project sources for potential bugs.
It uses one or more options inside a lintOptions block.  One of these options is [baseline](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/lint-in-studio-2-3), which allows snapshots of current sets of warnings in Lint.  It takes in a file path and can do this one of two ways:

One way uses a method called file() after it, which records all current issues in the file provided:

```
android {
    lintOptions {
        baseline file("lint-baseline.xml") // your choice of filename/path here
    }
}
```

Another way uses method called configFile()

```
android{
     ...
     lintOptions {
        baseline configFile('quality/lint/lint-baseline.xml')
     }
     ...
}
```

which seems like it has a similar use, but I have found no documentation confirming or denying this.

## Question

What is configFile() and how does it differ from file() in Lint?